# キーバリューになっているobject型から値を取得する方法について

Tags: c#

お世話になります。
C#のobject型から値を取得したいと思っております。以下のコードからhoge2の値である「"2"」を取得するにはどうしたら良いでしょうか？ご教授お願いします。

```
object obj = new { hoge = 1, hoge2 = "2"};
```

Comment: ちなみになぜそのようなアクセス方法が必要になっているのでしょうか？ 何か道を踏み外していたりしませんか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ちょっと大変ですが、 [GetValue(Object)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Reflection_PropertyInfo_GetValue_System_Object_) と [動的にGetType()で得られる型に変換するには](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/tueda_wolf/20141211/p1) の組み合わせで、こんな風にキー名を指定して型と値が取得できます。
まあ、もっと簡潔なやり方はあるのでしょうけれど。
あとここでは、バリューが配列とか複合型の場合については省略です。

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            object obj = new { hoge = 1, hoge2 = "2" };

            string key = "hoge2";
            object value = GetValueByKeyName(obj, key);
            if (value != null)
            {
                Type t = value.GetType();
                var v = Convert.ChangeType(value, t);
                Console.WriteLine("{0} type is: {1}, value is: {2}", key, t.Name, v.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} does not exist", key);
            }
            return;
        }

        private static object GetValueByKeyName(object obj, string name)
        {
            object result = null;
            Type t = obj.GetType();
            PropertyInfo[] props = t.GetProperties();
            foreach (var prop in props)
            {
                if (prop.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0)
                {
                    if (prop.Name.Equals(name))
                    {
                        result = prop.GetValue(obj);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: なるほど！プロパティ使ってGetValueすれば取れたんですね（なぜこの考えに行き着かないのか）！今回のケースでは、バリューが配列とか複合型は省くのでこちらがベストです！ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 4):

動的型付け変数を使えば可能です。

```
object obj = new { hoge = 1, hoge2 = "2" };

dynamic d = obj;
Console.WriteLine(d.hoge2);
```

ただし動的型付け変数を多用すると静的型付け言語であるC#のメリットをがなくなり、
動的型付けのデメリットが発生します。
結果、静的型付けのデメリットと動的型付けのデメリットの両方があるひどいプログラムになってしまいます。

Comment: dynamicだと動的にプロパティを指定出来ないのでちょっと今回は断念しました。。質問の仕方が悪くてすみません。。

Comment: 「取り出すたびにdynamicに入れ直さないといけないのが大変だから」ということなのでしょうか。ExpandoObjectと組み合わせれば良いような気がします。（乱用するとhihijijiさんのおっしゃってる通りデメリットもでてきますので、分離された箇所で使ったほうがいいでしょう）質問と目的が離れるのでコメントで失礼。

Comment: >「取り出すたびにdynamicに入れ直さないといけないのが大変だから」
いえ、obj内のプロパティは任意のものを想定しており（hogeもbarもそれ以外のある）、dynamicだとd.hoge2のように決まったプロパティ名しか指定出来ないので今回のパターンに沿いませんでした。でもExpandoObjectを知らなかったのですが、Dictionaryと組み合わせてValueをとれるのでこれが一番いいかもしれません！ありがとうございます!

Comment: dynamicも決まったプロパティ名ではありませんよ（コード内で決定できず外部テキストからしか、つまりコンパイル時には決まらないならそうですが）。ちなみにXMLパーサとかjsonパーサが欲しいのであればライブラリを探す方がいいかもしれません。

Comment: > dynamicも決まったプロパティ名ではありませんよ
その通りですね、、動的（プログラム実行中にプロパティ名が決まる）に指定しなければいけないのでdynamicだとdictionaryみたいにhoge["hogehoge"]みたいに取れないので今回は断念しました。今回はkunifさんの案で実装しようかと思います。